# Css a:hover:after:nth-child 1,2,3,4,5 content in dropdown navbar not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

I created a simple navbar and I would love to add some css-nth-child:before to the menu depending on the main category

The dropdown navbar has 5 different categories:

```
News, Politics, Economy, Health and Education
```

Each category has its own subcategories with region names like this:

```
Europe, Asia, Africa, Oceania, North America and South America
```

What I want is:
when people put their mouse over (hover) lets say category: Politics, and the mouse is over the Politics sub-categories, on hover I want to display like this:

```
Politics news from Europe
Politics news from Asia
Politics news from Africa
etc
```

But if the mouse is over (hover) the category Economy and the mouse is over the Economy  sub-categories, on hover I want to display like this:

```
Economy news from Europe
Economy news from Asia
Economy news from Africa
etc
```

What I tried is the following CSS

```
    sub-categories a:hover:after:nth-child(2)  
    {content: 'Politics news from • ';
    sub-categories a:hover:after:nth-child(3)  
    {content: 'Economy news from • ';
    sub-categories a:hover:after:nth-child(4)  
    {content: 'Health news from • ';
```

But it is not working

Here is the HTML

```
<main-categories><a href="#void"><strong>▪</strong>News</a>
  <sub-categories>
    <a href="#">Sweden</a>
    <a href="#">Europe</a>
    <a href="#">Asia</a>
    <a href="#">Africa</a>
    <a href="#">Oceania</a>
    <a href="#">North America</a>
    <a href="#">South America</a>
  </sub-categories>
</main-categories>

<main-categories><a href="#void"><strong>▪</strong>Politics</a>
  <sub-categories>
    <a href="#">Sweden</a>
    <a href="#">Europe</a>
    <a href="#">Asia</a>
    <a href="#">Africa</a>
    <a href="#">Oceania</a>
    <a href="#">North America</a>
    <a href="#">South America</a>
  </sub-categories>
</main-categories>

<main-categories><a href="#void"><strong>▪</strong>Economy</a>
  <sub-categories>
    <a href="#">Sweden</a>
    <a href="#">Europe</a>
    <a href="#">Asia</a>
    <a href="#">Africa</a>
    <a href="#">Oceania</a>
    <a href="#">North America</a>
    <a href="#">South America</a>
  </sub-categories>
</main-categories>

<main-categories><a href="#void"><strong>▪</strong>Health</a>
  <sub-categories>
    <a href="#">Sweden</a>
    <a href="#">Europe</a>
    <a href="#">Asia</a>
    <a href="#">Africa</a>
    <a href="#">Oceania</a>
    <a href="#">North America</a>
    <a href="#">South America</a>
  </sub-categories>
</main-categories>
```

and the CSS is

```
main-categories 
{position:relative;display:block;
text-align:left;width:92%;margin:0 auto;overflow:hidden;}
main-categories a 
{position:relative;margin:0 auto;display:block;
font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:left;padding:12px 0 12px 0;width:100%;
border-bottom:1px dotted #121212;overflow:hidden}
main-categories a:last-child 
{border:0}  
main-categories a:hover 
{text-decoration:none;
color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#121212;padding-left:13px;}
main-categories:last-child 
{border:0}
sub-categories {display:none;position:relative;width:90%;
left:50%;transform:translatex(-50%);
text-align:left;overflow:hidden}
sub-categories a 
{display:block;font-size:15px;color:#121212;
text-transform:capitalize;padding:10px 0 10px 0;text-align:left;
border-bottom:1px dotted #121212}
sub-categories a:hover 
{color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#121212;padding-left:20px;}
sub-categories a:last-child
 {border-bottom:1px dotted #121212} 
main-categories:hover sub-categories 
{display:block}
sub-categories a:before{content: '• ';}
sub-categories a:hover:after:nth-child(1) 
 {content: 'News from • ';
sub-categories a:hover:after:nth-child(1) 
 {content: 'Politics from • ';
sub-categories a:hover:after:nth-child(1) 
 {content: 'Economy from • ';
```

I also created a Codepen to see it live

https://codepen.io/familias/pen/XWygWzY

Comment: Your nth-child selector needs to be on the main-category element, then sub-category and subsequent pseudo class and selector = `main-categories:nth-child(1) sub-categories a:hover::before` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working in an IDE? Because your last CSS is broken and missing closing brackets. Working in an IDE would help you out a lot.

You can achieve this effect by using the `nth-of-type()` operater on `main-categories`. Example:

```
main-categories:nth-of-type(1) sub-categories a:hover:before {
    content: '• News from ';
}

main-categories:nth-of-type(2) sub-categories a:hover:before {
    content: '• Political news from ';
}
```

```css
main-categories {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
     text-align:left;
    width:92%;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
 main-categories a {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
     font-size:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
     text-align:left;
    padding:12px 0 12px 0;
    width:100%;
     border-bottom:1px dotted #121212;
    overflow:hidden
}
 main-categories a:last-child {
    border:0
}
 main-categories a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
     color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#121212;
    padding-left:13px;
}
 main-categories:last-child {
    border:0
}
 sub-categories {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
     left:50%;
    transform:translatex(-50%);
     text-align:left;
    overflow:hidden
}
 sub-categories a {
    display:block;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#121212;
     text-transform:capitalize;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    text-align:left;
     border-bottom:1px dotted #121212
}
 sub-categories a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#121212;
    padding-left:20px;
}
 sub-categories a:last-child {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #121212
}
 main-categories:hover sub-categories {
    display:block
}
 sub-categories a:before{
    content: '• ';
}
main-categories:nth-of-type(1) sub-categories a:hover:before {
    content: '• News from ';
}

main-categories:nth-of-type(2) sub-categories a:hover:before {
    content: '• Political news from ';
}
```

```html
<main-categories><a href="#void"><strong>▪</strong>News</a>
  <sub-categories>
    <a href="#">Sweden</a>
    <a href="#">Europe</a>
    <a href="#">Asia</a>
    <a href="#">Africa</a>
    <a href="#">Oceania</a>
    <a href="#">North America</a>
    <a href="#">South America</a>
  </sub-categories>
</main-categories>

<main-categories><a href="#void"><strong>▪</strong>Politics</a>
  <sub-categories>
    <a href="#">Sweden</a>
    <a href="#">Europe</a>
    <a href="#">Asia</a>
    <a href="#">Africa</a>
    <a href="#">Oceania</a>
    <a href="#">North America</a>
    <a href="#">South America</a>
  </sub-categories>
</main-categories>

<main-categories><a href="#void"><strong>▪</strong>Economy</a>
  <sub-categories>
    <a href="#">Sweden</a>
    <a href="#">Europe</a>
    <a href="#">Asia</a>
    <a href="#">Africa</a>
    <a href="#">Oceania</a>
    <a href="#">North America</a>
    <a href="#">South America</a>
  </sub-categories>
</main-categories>

<main-categories><a href="#void"><strong>▪</strong>Health</a>
  <sub-categories>
    <a href="#">Sweden</a>
    <a href="#">Europe</a>
    <a href="#">Asia</a>
    <a href="#">Africa</a>
    <a href="#">Oceania</a>
    <a href="#">North America</a>
    <a href="#">South America</a>
  </sub-categories>
</main-categories>
```

Comment: It worked perfect and I learned something new thanks to you